# How to quickly find all transparent objects in an artwork in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, eps, plugin, flatten

I have document with 15000 paths. I used a lot blending modes, blur effects and gradients with transparent nodes. I need to convert it to EPS. I found most of transparent objects, but over 50 more I'm not able to find by myself. Flattener preview in Transparent objects isn't showing anything. But in All affected objects there are quite a lot of red space. Is there any script or plugin that helps in finding transparent objects?

Answer (score 1):

You could make a transparent box, select it and then got to Select > Same Fill Color

Some options under Select > Object may also be handy for you.

Comment: Tried, it doesn't find gradients with transparent node. I'm looking a script or pluging that can select all transparent objects, that are written in info panel.

Answer (score 1):

The "*flattener - preview*" is the right tool to use. The '*Transparent objects'* will show objects that have transparency properties (blending modes/opacity less than 100%) and the *'All Affected objects'* shows any element that may be affected by some element of transparency. For example some type with a drop shadow. The type itself may not have transparency but the drop shadow does and if this sits on top of other elements then these are affected. When looking for transparent objects, consider what other objects these are integrated with as these are also affected by the transparency.

Comment: Flattener preview only shows objects that are visible, but what to do if transparent object is hidden behind other objects?